# Adding net banking and debit card as payment option in a commercial website

Tags: paypal, onlinebanking

Now a days websites have large number of payment options for a user (examples being yebhi.com jabong.com snapdeal.com) like Net banking(when a user selects this option , he gets a list of banks in that country and then he selects a particular bank and proceeds with payment),debit card. I wanted to integrate these two options in my website. Payment option with credit card i guess can be done with paypal widgets . Can anyone help me with this.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Payment options are added to website using payment gateways. Each of them will have their of features and commission rate. Take a quick at the most popular gateways. Below is also the link in wikihow on integrating payment gateway to the site

http://www.wikihow.com/Integrate-a-Payment-Gateway-Into-a-Website

Enets – www.enets.com

AsiaPay – www.asiapay.com

GT Payment – www.gtpayment.com

Paypal - www.paypal.com

WorldPay – www.worldpay.com

2Checkout – www.2checkout.com

Globalcollect – www.globalcollect.com